# Is it possible to tweak Gnome to behave more like i3 when it comes to shifting focus among windows?

Tags: gnome

I have to use Gnome due to certain integrations. However, I'm very much familiar with i3, and I was wondering whether it's possible to tweak Gnome to do the following.

In i3, you can switch among windows by pressing `SUPER + LEFT/RIGHT`. This will not only change the focus but it will also move the cursor over the newly focused window. Is it possible to do this in Gnome?

I know that in Gnome, you can press `SUPER + TAB` to change focus among various windows, but it does not seem to move the cursor along. The same thing occurs when moving a window to another monitor (`SUPER + SHIFT + LEFT/RIGHT`) - the window moves but the cursor does not.

So ultimately, I would like the cursor to follow focus.